# PHP - extract() type

Tags: php, extract, exists, prefix

PHP's [`extract()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function can take on one of several `extract_types`. But what's the difference between `extr_prefix_same` and `extr_prefix_if_exists`? The manual makes it sound like, in either case, new variables will be prefixed if the variable name already exists.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `EXTR_PREFIX_IF_EXISTS`, if the variable doesn't already exist then the prefixed version won't be created either. In this example:

```
function test() {
    $a = 12345;

    extract(array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3), EXTR_PREFIX_IF_EXISTS, 'my_');

    var_export(get_defined_vars());
}
test();
```

`$my_b` and `$my_c` aren't created because `$b` and `$c` don't exist.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Was reading too quickly and missed the connection to `EXTR_IF_EXISTS`. Makes perfect sense now.

Thanks to Alan Storm and jason below, too.

Comment: The wording in the manual isn't clear at all - I had to run some experiments to figure out how it behaves.

Answer (score 2):

`EXTR_PREFIX_SAME` will extract *all* variables, and only prefix ones that exist in the current scope.

`EXTR_PREFIX_IF_EXISTS` will *only* extract variables that exist in the current scope, and prefix them with the desired prefix.

So, for example:

```
$foo = 'foo';
$bar = 'bar';

extract(array('foo' => 'moo', 'bar' => 'mar', 'baz' => 'maz'), EXTR_PREFIX_IF_EXISTS, 'prefix');

isset($prefix_foo); // true
isset($prefix_baz); // false
isset($baz); // false
```

While....

```
$foo = 'foo';
$bar = 'bar';

extract(array('foo' => 'moo', 'bar' => 'mar', 'baz' => 'maz'), EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, 'prefix');

isset($prefix_foo); // true
isset($prefix_baz); // false
isset($baz); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the manual definitions, `EXTR_PREFIX_SAME` will create variables based on the key name, and if a variable in the local space already exists, a prefix will be added to the variable name.

By contrast, `EXTR_PREFIX_IF_EXISTS` would appear to inherit the behavior of `EXTR_IF_EXISTS` (only overwrite if the variables already exist), but instead of overwriting the local variables, a prefixed version will be created.

Consider the following

```
$array = Array();
$array['foo'] = 'foo';
$array['bar'] = 'bar';
$array['baz'] = 'baz';  

$foo = 'local foo';
$bar = 'local bar';

extract($array, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, 'pre');

print_r(get_defined_vars());

//partial output    
//Array
//(
//  [array] => Array
//      (
//          [foo] => foo
//          [bar] => bar
//          [baz] => baz
//      )
//
//  [foo] => local foo
//  [bar] => local bar
//  [pre_foo] => foo
//  [pre_bar] => bar
//  [baz] => baz
//)
```

So with `EXTR_PREFIX_SAME`, the values of $foo and $bar will remain the same, and three new local variables ($pre_foo, $pre_bar, and $baz) will be defined.  However if we use `EXTR_PREFIX_IF_EXISTS`

```
$array = Array();
$array['foo'] = 'foo';
$array['bar'] = 'bar';
$array['baz'] = 'baz';  

$foo = 'local foo';
$bar = 'local bar';

extract($array, EXTR_PREFIX_IF_EXISTS, 'pre');

print_r(get_defined_vars());

//partial output    
//Array
//(
//  [array] => Array
//      (
//          [foo] => foo
//          [bar] => bar
//          [baz] => baz
//      )
//
//  [foo] => local foo
//  [bar] => local bar
//  [pre_foo] => foo
//  [pre_bar] => bar
//)
```

The values of $foo and $bar are still preserved, but only TWO new variables are imported into the local space.  Since $baz isn't a variable that already exists the `EXTR_PREFIX_IF_EXISTS` tells PHP to ignore the 'baz' key in the array.